# Getting the third number occurrence in a string

Tags: ruby

Right now I'm scrapping this:

> (178,979)

with this:

```
.text[/[\d,]+/]
```

to turn it into this:

```
178,979
```

Now I want to scrap this:

> Showing 1 - 24 of 512,518 Results

and turn it into this:

```
512,518
```

What's the easiest way of accomplishing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go about it something like this:

```
'Showing 1 - 24 of 512,518 Results'[/\d+,\d+/] # => "512,518"
```

Or this:

```
'Showing 1 - 24 of 512,518 Results'[/(\S+) Results$/i, 1] # => "512,518"
```

Comment: The second one look good. The first one is likely to fail for larger values (`'Showing 100,001 - 100,024 of...'`).

Answer (score 1):

```
str = 'Showing 1 - 24 of 512,518 Results'
str.scan(/[\d,]+/)[2]
#=> "512,518"
str[/\d+,\d+/]
#=> "512,518"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an integer, followed by a comma, again followed by an integer. So this regex should do the trick:

```
/\d+,\d+/
```